# Writing to /dev/loop USB image?

Tags: image, loops, usb

I've got an image that I write onto a bootable USB that I need to tweak.  I've managed to mount the stick as /dev/loopX including allowing for the partition start offset, and I can read files from it.  However writing back 'seems to work' (no errors reported) but after writing the resulting tweaked image to a USB drive, I can no longer read the tweaked files correctly.
The file that fails is large and also a compressed tarfile.
Is writing back in this manner simply a 'no-no' or is there some way to make this work?
If possible, I don't want to reformat the partition and rewrite from scratch because that will (I assume) change the UUID and then I need to go worry about the boot partition etc.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have the answer.  When using losetup to create a writeable virtual device from the partition on your USB drive, you must specify the --sizelimit parameter as well as the offset parameter.  If you don't then the resulting writes can go past the last defined sector on the partition (presumably requires your USB drive to have extra space).  Linux reports no errors until later when you try to read.  The key hints/evidence for this are that when reads (or (re)written data) fail, dmesg shows read errors attempting to read past the end of the drive.  fsck tools such as dosfsck also indicate that the drive claims to be larger than it is.